# Calculate all permutations for a hex string

Tags: python-2.7, hex, permutation

I'd like to calculate all permutations for a hex string. From 000000000000 to FFFFFFFFFFFF.
Currently I'm using this code;

```
def calc_hex(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

f = calc_hex('0123456789ABCDEF', 12)
```

But not all combinations are calculated (eg. 0022FB4D31F8 is missing).

What's going wrong ?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `if not n and r:` should be `if not n and not r:`?

Comment: You say "permutations", but you also say "combinations", and I think you might mean something more like "Cartesian product".  Those are three different things.  In any case, there are way more than you could loop over anyway-- are you sure this is really what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that *"all permutations of a hex string"* is really just the hex representations of all integers in the appropriate range (`0` to `281474976710655`, in this case), why not:

```
def hex_perms(digits=12):
    x = 0
    max_ = 16 ** digits
    while x < max_:
        yield '{:0{len}X}'.format(x, len=digits)
        x += 1
```

Note that you can't use `xrange` because `Python int too large to convert to C long` for `16**12`.

Comment: So would this be good for brute forcing a password; containing only characters {0..9}{A..F}?

Comment: @tjt263 yes, I suppose so.

Comment: Cool, I was just confused because you said *"just the hex representations of all integers"*. I thought maybe that was referring to something similar but different. Should this work with all versions of Python? I tried running it with `python2.5` (because it was available). But it seems to produce no output.

Comment: @tjt263 how did you try running it? Just calling the function will create a generator, then you need to iterate over it. Also why 2.5?! That's very old now.

Comment: Oh okay, that would be why. I'm still getting the hang of Python. So this just defines the function `hex_perms` then, right? How do I iterate over it? And 2.5 just because it was already installed on the old jail-broken iPad I was using.

Comment: @tjt263 `for perm in hex_perms(4): print perm`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Cool. Okay this is good. Can I just ask one more thing? Why `(4):`?

Comment: @tjt263 why not? Pick any number you like, but the larger it is the longer it takes. That's the `digits` argument.

Comment: That's what I thought; but isn't it already defined as 12? *i.e. **`def hex_perms(digits=12):`**?* It's the very first line.

Comment: @tjt263 yep, but watching that all print out will be slow so I picked a smaller one.